# How do I eliminate tub spout gap?

Tags: plumbing, shower, bathtub

I have a gap between the tub spout and the tile wall.

How would I straighten the pipe?

I’ve included two photos. One to show the spout and the other to show the copper pipe. This is a condo complex so somewhat challenging to turn off the water to the building. The shower valve has stops.

Separately, if I use caulk, which type do you recommend?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the problem that the pipe slopes downward? That's not initially apparent, but you sort of imply it by the question.

Comment: What pipe are you looking to "straighten" and in what way? You mention that as a throw-away comment, but give us no info about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either shorten the pipe or caulk the gap; neither would require shutting the water off (just don't open the valve while working on it).

I would just caulk it, it's not that big of a gap. Use silicone caulk labeled for use in the tub/shower/bath environment.

Comment: I will most likely use silicone. I don’t see how shortening the pipe will fix the problem since the gap is larger at the top. It appears the pipe is angled slightly downwards. Any suggestions on how to fix if I was to adjust the pipe or put in a new pipe?

Comment: You might try searching the site,there are some already answered questions that might help you: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/209367/how-do-i-eliminate-tub-spout-gap?r=SearchResults&s=2|84.4575

Comment: The soft copper was probably bent and that is the reason for the difference in the gap, someone that did understand how to install this properly in the first place may not have anchored the 90.

Comment: I have also seen cheap imported tub spouts where the threaded boss inside was not straight and true...

Comment: It’s a brand new Moen filler. I have searched the site for other answers. I’m not going to bend the pipe since it’s a condo. I was hoping someone could see the joint in the copper and suggest an easyish fix, such as using a deep socket and replacing the pipe. The good. We’d is that waterproofing with silicone is an easy fix.

Comment: Try one last thing: remove the spout and pipe and remove all vestiges of pipe thread compound and/or teflon tape. Rewrap with 3 wraps of teflon and screw the pipe in, watching for an elliptical movement indicating a bend in the pipe. If elliptical, Try to stop tightening when the pipe ellipse lands closest to perpendicular to the wall surface. You don't want a leak in the wall, but remember that this is an open-ended assembly and not subject to high pressure. NOTE- if the pipe ain't bent then the assembly in the wall is to blame and there's not much you can do short of tearing open the wall.

Comment: You can see the pipe is threaded in, so if it is bent you could just replace it with a brand new (straight) brass nipple of the proper length.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you can simply spin the spout on further. To find out, spin it off and clean both the male and female threads with a toothbrush or metal bristle brush. Spin it back on. If it goes snug to the wall, add a few wraps of PTFE tape to the pipe stub and reinstall. Some trial and error may be needed to figure out how much tape is the right amount.

If it won't go all the way, at least now you can see what you'd have to do to shorten the stub so you can. A quick de-sweat, pipe trim, and re-sweat is worth the aesthetic outcome, in my opinion.

Caulk would look crappy on a gap like that. (Caulk always looks crappy on tub spouts.) I would caulk around the pipe, though. Fill the entire void to the tile with silicone.